# How to connect multiple Dockers to different bridges in a single host machine?

Tags: networking, docker, ubuntu-14.04

Is it possible to connect multiple Dockers (in my case, multiple instances of the same docker) each to different bridge in a single host machine?

3rd party solutions like pipework recommends first looking for "native" ways.

Something like that:

[image]

When I start 2 instance, the 1st use by default docker0 bridge, while the 2nd is instructed to use br1 (different IP range) :

```
sudo docker run -t -i me/tester:latest /bin/bash
sudo docker --bridge=br1 run -t -i me/tester:latest /bin/bash
```

results in both having the same IP range from Doker0:

```
root@2a259a88d9c8:/# ip a
...
73: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:d7:cc:c8:b7:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.32/16 scope global eth0
```

--

```
root@0b849a5398af:/# ip a
...
79: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:84:ad:6c:70:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.34/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how it is done using the new native docker networking:

**Create docker networks (linux bridges) with a predefined subnets**

```
docker network create --subnet=192.168.10.0/24 net1
docker network create --subnet=192.168.20.0/24 net2
docker network create --subnet=192.168.30.0/24 net3
```

**The created networks correspond to linux bridges**

```
brctl show
```

[image]

**Create tap interfaces**

```
sudo ip tuntap add dev tap1 mode tap
sudo ip tuntap add dev tap2 mode tap
sudo ip tuntap add dev tap3 mode tap
```

**and join them to the bridges**

```
sudo brctl addif br-a24f2eb2e054 tap1
sudo brctl addif br-d28c0759c37a tap2
sudo brctl addif br-d9512f62e471 tap3
```

**starting your containers**

```
sudo docker run -itd --name=c1  phusion/baseimage
sudo docker run -itd --name=c2  phusion/baseimage
sudo docker run -itd --name=c3  phusion/baseimage
```

**Connecting containers to network**

```
docker network connect net1 c1
docker network connect net2 c2
docker network connect net3 c3
```

**Verify that each container is connected to its network**

```
docker network inspect net1
```

[image]

```
docker network inspect net2
```

[image]

```
docker network inspect net3
```

[image]

**Connected containers get their ip from their corresponding network subnets**

```
docker exec c1 ip a s eth1
```

[image]

```
docker exec c2 ip a s eth1
```

[image]

```
docker exec c3 ip a s eth1
```

[image]

**Disconnecting containers from networks**

```
docker network disconnect net1 c1
docker network disconnect net2 c2
docker network disconnect net3 c3
```

**Remove the networks**

```
docker network rm net1
docker network rm net2
docker network rm net3
```

Comment: Very good tutorial. Can this also be done by configuration like docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [custom bridges](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge) and then run each container with the option `-b <BRIDGE>` or `--bridge=<BRIDGE>`, but I have not try this and I wouldn't be absolutely sure that this approach works without any issue. If you read [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8678) Docker issue, I think the suggest it is not possible this way.

But as commented in [that](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8678) issue, you can disable any docker network management (running the container with the option `--net=none`, and then organize the network as you wish using [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework).

Finally you can take a look of [zettio/weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave). Using it you can run easily each container in the network you wish, and also it gives you a lot of possibilities if you want to expand your docker environment from one to various machines (as docker swarm does).

Comment: Still both "sudo docker run -t -i me/tester:latest /bin/bash" and "sudo docker --bridge=br1 run -t -i me/tester:latest /bin/bash" have the same IP range from Dcoker0.

Comment: Got answer from Docker forum that it is under an ongoing project and the issue will be addressed in version 1.6-1.7 or so.

Comment: you can't run each container in a different bridge, the `--bridge` option is set on the daemon for all containers

Comment: Hey all, now that we're on 1.10, what does this look like?